# Позиционирование текста

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Создал `Text t = new Text("some text");`.

Прикрепил его к `grid` через `add`, т.к. он не захотел появляться на апплете, к ячейке `0,0`. Ок, появился, но он не позиционируется. Никак. Невозможно сделать отступы через `.setX()`, `.setY()`.
Если убираю его с грида (просто создаю текст), то тогда он вообще не появляется на  сцене.

Что я делаю не так? Может быть через `.setStyle()` как-то можно добиться успеха?

Comment: Так вроде add и указывает координаты ячейки.   add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex). И о каких отступах идет речь? В самом гриде настраивается или позиционирование объектов или ширина разделителей ячеек.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте статический метод setAlignment() класса GridPane и метод setMargin() класса Text. Могу ошибаться в названии в плане точного написания. Суть в том, что первый задает выравнивание внутри контейнера, а второй - задает отступы от границ контейнера. Экспериментируйте!

Comment: Пробовал, да не вышло. Сдается мне, неправильно организовал я работу приложения. Просто я запарился уже разбираться.
Самое смешное: я меняю длину кнопки, а пропадает целый столбец кнопок. )) Видимо, это из-за того, что размер ячеек автоматом подстраивается под размер кнопок.  
Я без веб-билдера и FXML делал. Может, в новом проекте следовало бы выбрать второй способ - намного быстрее бы вышло...

Comment: FXML сильно упрощает разработку интерфейса. Попробуйте ещё метод setPadding(), я мог их перепутать с setMargin(). Относительно пропадания столбца кнопок - ничего сказать не могу, надо смотреть код. Кстати, может сбросите, посмотрим.

Comment: Да, конечно, просто он очень *грязный*:

http://pastebin.com/dMbfKaRR

Сюда не влезает))
По поводу FXML: Дело в том, что я удалил привязку к sample.fxml, а кода-то там больше нет... откуда ему взять FXML именно измененный(т.е. код моего проекта) ?))

Никогда не писал приложений на JavaFX и swing, потому и сразу сложности с архитектурой приложений возникли))).

Comment: Может, сразу весь проект куда-нибудь выложить? А то там css и прочее...)

Comment: Так. Я тут вижу, что вы применяете метод setPadding() для объекта grid, то есть задаете рамку для самой таблицы, но не применяете ни к одному объекту класса Text. Попробуйте что-нибудь из серии

    sceneTitle.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));

Или же

    sceneTitle.setMargin(new Insets(25,25,25,25));

Comment: Попробую. Я тут новый GUI накатал уже для формы, очень даже неплохо смотрится. ) Думаю, лучше вообще программно GUI не создавать, а всё-таки раобраться с билдером/FXML, как Вы и советовали. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, программно интерфейс лучше не задавать. Его надо задавать программно, когда он должен создаваться программно. То есть, создается основа через FXML, затем через метод initialize() класса-контроллера заполняется.